# Java LRU with random insertion

Tags: java, caching, collections, lru

I'm building an LRU cache in Java - basically a size constrained linkedhashmap that inserts items to the head of a list when first fetched,  drops them when they hit the end of the list, and moves them to the front of the list when accessed.

But there's a twist.   I want to be able to insert into the middle of the list depending on how likely I think the item is to be fetched.   Inserting into the middle of the list would mean the item would be in "cache" for less time and use up less space.

I can't see how to insert into the middle of a linkedhashmap,  any other options?

Comment: This...isn't LRU, then.  And there's no way to do it with the built-in `LinkedHashMap`; you'd have to build your own data structure -- and generally there's not an efficient way to insert into a desired location in the middle of any kind of linked list.

Comment: No, not really.  You're almost certainly better off using something preexisting with a more conventional eviction policy.

Comment: If you want as much of my time as it'll take to build a whole new data structure, you can pay me for it.  I'm here to give help to people who have tried to solve their problems and have the effort to show for it, not to solve their problems from scratch.

Comment: I can outline some ideas I have - keep your entries in a priority queue, balanced binary tree, or skip list - but I can also tell you that that'll take O(log n), I can tell you it's going to require a custom data structure, I can tell you I'm not aware of any third party libraries that provide anything like that, and I can tell you I'm not going to code this for you from scratch.

Comment: [Design of a Modern Cache](http://highscalability.com/blog/2016/1/25/design-of-a-modern-cache.html) should provide ideas, links to explore, and reference code.

Comment: Another trick to insert into the "middle" of an LRU: you could encode it into a flat array with an access timestamps. Then take a random sample to probabilistically guess at a mid element, link as the neighbor, and use the calculated middle access timestamp. Don't expect this to be worth the effort, though.